# SQL Paged query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've the following SQL structure:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT subquery.* FROM (
        SELECT some_columns
        FROM some_tables
        WHERE junctions_critereas
        GROUP BY some_columns
      UNION
        SELECT some_columns
        FROM some_tables
        WHERE junctions_critereas
        GROUP BY some_columns) subquery
    GROUP BY some_columns)
WHERE ROWNUM > startRecord AND ROWNUM <= endRecord;
```

- If I exclude the ROWNUM criterea the query returns 33 records.
- If I put startRecord = 0 and endRecord = 10 the query returns the 10 first
  records.
- If I put startRecord = 0 and endRecord = 20 the query returns the 20 first records.
- If I put startRecord = 0 and endRecord = 40 the query returns all the 33 records.
- If I put startRecord = 10 and endRecord = 20 the query returns no records.

If I change the final WHERE to `WHERE ROWNUM BETEEW startRecord AND endRecord` I got the same results.

Some one knows what's happening here?

Comment: Your example here has `ROWNUM < startRecord`. I assume it should be looking for `ROWNUM > startRecord`

Answer (score 2):

(Note:  I'm assuming that the first condition is really `ROWNUM < startRecord` as @RToyota points out in a comment.)

The Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) is very clear about this:

> Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer
>   are always false. For example, this query returns no rows:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM employees
>     WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
> ```
>
> The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the
>   condition false. The second row to be fetched is now the first row and
>   is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. All rows
>   subsequently fail to satisfy the condition, so no rows are returned.

In Oracle 12c, you can use `OFFSET`/`FETCH NEXT`.  In earlier versions, you can either use `row_number()` or nest queries with offsets.

Comment: I solved this in other way... But I can't post my answer...